# Error en stored procedure: Subquery returned more than 1 value

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014

Tengo este stored procedure. Nunca había tenido errores a la hora de ejecutarse. Pero desde ayer me manda este mensaje de error.

> Msg 512, Level 16, State 1, Procedure
>   SPFS_LAMINA_OBTIENE_LOCALIZACIONRESPALDO, Line 76 Subquery returned
>   more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =,
>   !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.

Estuve investigando y puede ser que porque haya algun registro duplicado. O no sé si estoy mal. El error me lo da en esta parte 
`WHERE FS.Cod_Reg = @COD_REG_SALDO_ROTOR AND FS.Lamina =  @LAMINA_SALDO_ROTOR)`.

Cualquier ayuda sería bienvenida. Y muchas gracias!

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[SPFS_LAMINA_OBTIENE_LOCALIZACIONRESPALDO]
--EXEC SPFS_LAMINA_OBTIENE_LOCALIZACIONRESPALDO
AS
BEGIN

SET NOCOUNT ON; 

TRUNCATE TABLE TBL_FS_Lamina_Surtida_Localizacion


DECLARE @EMRAlllnventory_Suma AS TABLE(
[ID] [int] IDENTITY (1,1),
[Col001] [char](18) NULL,
[Col004] [float] NULL,
[Col006] [char](11) NULL 
) 

INSERT INTO @EMRAlllnventory_Suma (Col001,Col004,Col006)
SELECT Col001,SUM(Col004),Col006 FROM TBL_FS_ALL_INVENTORY WITH (NOLOCK) 
WHERE RTRIM(LTRIM(UPPER(Col006))) = 'C' AND Tipo like '%Lamina%'
GROUP BY Col001, Col006

--select * from @EMRAlllnventory_Suma


DECLARE @EMRAlllnventory AS TABLE(
[ID] [int] IDENTITY (1,1),
[Col001] [char](18) NULL,
[Col004] [float] NULL,
[Col006] [char](11) NULL,
[Col007] [char](12) NULL,
[Total] [int] NULL
) 


INSERT INTO @EMRAlllnventory (Col001,Col004,Col006,Col007)
SELECT Col001,Col004,Col006,Col007 FROM TBL_FS_ALL_INVENTORY WITH (NOLOCK) 
WHERE RTRIM(LTRIM(UPPER(Col006))) = 'C'  AND Col001 IN (SELECT DISTINCT Lamina FROM TBL_FS_ROTOR_LAMINA_SOLICITADA WHERE ESTATUS NOT IN (4, 5, 10, 11, 13, 15))
ORDER BY Col007 DESC

--select * from @EMRAlllnventory

UPDATE E SET E.Total = S.Col004 FROM @EMRAlllnventory E INNER JOIN @EMRAlllnventory_Suma S ON E.Col001 = S.Col001 


 DECLARE @SOLICITUDES AS TABLE(
    [ID] [int] IDENTITY (1,1),
    [Lamina] [varchar](19) NULL,
    [Cod_Reg] [VARCHAR] (MAX) null
) 


INSERT INTO @SOLICITUDES
SELECT DISTINCT LAMINA, COD_REG FROM TBL_FS_ROTOR_LAMINA_SOLICITADA WHERE ESTATUS NOT IN (4, 5, 10, 11, 13)


 DECLARE @CANTIDAD_SALDO_ROTOR INT, @CONT_SALDO_ROTOR INT = 1


 SET @CANTIDAD_SALDO_ROTOR = (SELECT COUNT(COD_REG) FROM @SOLICITUDES)


 WHILE @CONT_SALDO_ROTOR < = @CANTIDAD_SALDO_ROTOR
 BEGIN

    DECLARE @COD_REG_SALDO_ROTOR VARCHAR (MAX), @LAMINA_SALDO_ROTOR VARCHAR(20) 

    SET @COD_REG_SALDO_ROTOR = (SELECT COD_REG FROM @SOLICITUDES WHERE ID = @CONT_SALDO_ROTOR)
    SET @LAMINA_SALDO_ROTOR = (SELECT LAMINA FROM @SOLICITUDES WHERE ID = @CONT_SALDO_ROTOR)

    DECLARE @CantidadSolicitada FLOAT
    IF EXISTS (SELECT Cod_Reg FROM TBL_FS_SaldoRotor WITH (NOLOCK) WHERE Cod_Reg  = @COD_REG_SALDO_ROTOR)
    BEGIN

        SET @CantidadSolicitada =  (SELECT (Restante_RotorQTY * Stack) FROM TBL_FS_SaldoRotor FS WITH (NOLOCK) 
        WHERE FS.Cod_Reg = @COD_REG_SALDO_ROTOR AND FS.Lamina =  @LAMINA_SALDO_ROTOR)


    END
    ELSE
    BEGIN

        SET @CantidadSolicitada = (SELECT (SE.Restante_ERFQTY * SE.Stack) FROM TBL_FS_SaldoRotor_Cerradas FS WITH (NOLOCK)
        INNER JOIN TBL_FS_Saldo_ERF SE WITH (NOLOCK) ON FS.Cod_Reg = SE.Cod_Reg
        WHERE FS.Cod_Reg = @COD_REG_SALDO_ROTOR AND FS.Lamina =  @LAMINA_SALDO_ROTOR and fs.estatus != 5)

    END


    DECLARE @inventoryLamina AS TABLE(
    [ID] [int] IDENTITY (1,1),
    [Lamina] [varchar](19) NULL,
    [Ubicacion] [char](11) NULL,
    [CantidadSurtida] [float] NULL,
    [CantidadLocalizacion] [float] NULL,
    [TotalInventario] [int] NULL
) 


    ------  
    IF EXISTS (SELECT Col007 FROM @EMRAlllnventory WHERE Col004 = @CantidadSolicitada  AND Col001 = @LAMINA_SALDO_ROTOR AND Col007 NOT LIKE '%C.0%')
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO @inventoryLamina (Lamina, Ubicacion, CantidadSurtida, CantidadLocalizacion, TotalInventario)
        SELECT Col001, Col007, @CantidadSolicitada, Col004, Total FROM @EMRAlllnventory WHERE Col004 = @CantidadSolicitada AND Col001 = @LAMINA_SALDO_ROTOR ORDER BY ID ASC


    END
    ELSE
    BEGIN
        --------

        DECLARE @CONT INT = 1, @CANTIDAD INT
        DECLARE @CANTIDAD_SURTIDA_POR_LOCALIZACION INT = 0

        SET @CANTIDAD = (SELECT COUNT(ID) FROM @EMRAlllnventory)



        WHILE @CONT < = @CANTIDAD 
        BEGIN

            DECLARE  @SUMA INT = 0, @CANT_LOCALIZACION INT

            SET @CANT_LOCALIZACION = (SELECT Col004 FROM @EMRAlllnventory WHERE ID = @CONT)

            IF @CantidadSolicitada < =  @CANT_LOCALIZACION
            BEGIN

                IF @LAMINA_SALDO_ROTOR = (SELECT Col001 FROM @EMRAlllnventory WHERE ID = @CONT) 
                BEGIN


                    INSERT INTO @inventoryLamina (Lamina, Ubicacion, CantidadSurtida, CantidadLocalizacion, TotalInventario)
                    SELECT Col001, Col007, @CantidadSolicitada, Col004, Total FROM @EMRAlllnventory WHERE ID = @CONT
                    AND Col001 = @LAMINA_SALDO_ROTOR


                    SET @CONT = @CANTIDAD + 1
                END
                ELSE
                BEGIN
                 SET @CONT = @cont + 1
                END

            END
            ELSE
            BEGIN

                    IF @SUMA < @CantidadSolicitada 
                    BEGIN

                        IF (@LAMINA_SALDO_ROTOR) =  (SELECT Col001 FROM @EMRAlllnventory WHERE ID = @CONT )
                        BEGIN
                            INSERT INTO @inventoryLamina (Lamina, Ubicacion, CantidadSurtida, CantidadLocalizacion, TotalInventario)
                            SELECT Col001, Col007, Col004, Total,  Col004 FROM @EMRAlllnventory WHERE ID = @CONT
                            AND Col001 = @LAMINA_SALDO_ROTOR

                            SET @SUMA = @SUMA + @CANT_LOCALIZACION

                        END
                    END

                    SET @CONT = @CONT + 1
            END

            END --

        END



INSERT INTO TBL_FS_Lamina_Surtida_Localizacion (Cod_Reg, Lamina, CantidadSurtida, Localizacion, CantidadLocalizacion, FechaSolicitada, Estatus)
SELECT @COD_REG_SALDO_ROTOR, Lamina, CantidadSurtida, Ubicacion, CantidadLocalizacion, GETDATE(), 1 FROM @inventoryLamina where Lamina = @LAMINA_SALDO_ROTOR


DELETE  @inventoryLamina

    SET @CONT_SALDO_ROTOR = @CONT_SALDO_ROTOR +1
 END


END
```

Comment: Alguno de los SET que fijan valores a variables dentro del SP te está entregando más de una fila. Pruébalos para ver cuál te está dando más datos y por qué. Posiblemente tengas un bug al registrar los datos que se usan aquí

Answer (score 2):

Efectivamente, el error se produce en la sentencia

```
SET @CantidadSolicitada =  (SELECT (Restante_RotorQTY * Stack) FROM TBL_FS_SaldoRotor FS 
WITH (NOLOCK)
WHERE FS.Cod_Reg = @COD_REG_SALDO_ROTOR AND FS.Lamina =  @LAMINA_SALDO_ROTOR)
```

La combinación de los dos filtros "FS.Cod_Reg = @COD_REG_SALDO_ROTOR AND FS.Lamina" devuelve más de un registro. Deberás acotar mejor el WHERE o bien realizar una subconsulta del tipo

```
SET @CantidadSolicitada =  (SELECT (b.Restante_RotorQTY * b.Stack) FROM (
SELECT TOP 1 Restante_RotorQTY, Stack from TBL_FS_SaldoRotor FS WITH (NOLOCK) 
WHERE FS.Cod_Reg = @COD_REG_SALDO_ROTOR AND FS.Lamina =  @LAMINA_SALDO_ROTOR
) b)
```

Aunque en este último caso solo te servirá si los datos duplicados contienen el mismo valor de Restante_RotorQTY y Stack. Deberías comprobar los registros y ver si necesitas un filtro adicional, mejor si se conrresponde con la clave principal de la tabla "TBL_FS_SaldoRotor".

Comment: Hola Roger muchas gracias. Estuve revisando y hay un registro duplicado. Cosa que no debe de pasar, porque todos mis registros deben ser unicos. Me imagino que como me comentaron anteriormente alguien hizo un insert incorrecto. Y eso me genera el bug.

Comment: @NoéTorres Si no debe de haber filas duplicadas, es importante que crees un `CHECK CONSTRAINT` para evitar que se repita ese problema. De otra forma, tienes que cambiar el código para manejar filas duplicadas.

Comment: @Luis Cazares. Si es correcto Luis Cazares.. Y muchas gracias

Answer (score 1):

El error es porque estás tratando un resultado de una consulta como un valor escalar. Eso funciona bien cuando regresa una sola fila, pero en cuanto son múltiples, se genera ese error.

Según lo que puedo ver, el código problemático se encuentra  cerca de la línea 75.

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT Cod_Reg FROM TBL_FS_SaldoRotor WITH (NOLOCK) WHERE Cod_Reg  = @COD_REG_SALDO_ROTOR)
BEGIN
    --Esto puede generar un error
    SET @CantidadSolicitada =  (SELECT (Restante_RotorQTY * Stack) 
                                FROM TBL_FS_SaldoRotor FS WITH (NOLOCK) 
                                WHERE FS.Cod_Reg = @COD_REG_SALDO_ROTOR 
                                AND FS.Lamina =  @LAMINA_SALDO_ROTOR)


END
ELSE
BEGIN
    --Esto puede generar un error
    SET @CantidadSolicitada = (SELECT (SE.Restante_ERFQTY * SE.Stack) 
                                FROM TBL_FS_SaldoRotor_Cerradas FS WITH (NOLOCK)
                                INNER JOIN TBL_FS_Saldo_ERF SE WITH (NOLOCK) ON FS.Cod_Reg = SE.Cod_Reg
                                WHERE FS.Cod_Reg = @COD_REG_SALDO_ROTOR 
                                AND FS.Lamina =  @LAMINA_SALDO_ROTOR 
                                and fs.estatus != 5)
END
```

Para solucionarlo, lo más lógico puede ser usar una sumatoria `SELECT SUM(Restante_RotorQTY * Stack)` o limitar para solo tomar una fila `SELECT TOP (1) (Restante_RotorQTY * Stack)`. Sin embargo, la solución correcta depende de la lógica de negocio que utilices.

El procedimiento está lleno de código procedural, lo que no es óptimo y sería bueno eliminar todos esos ciclos explícitos. Sin embargo, eso va más allá del alcance de la pregunta.